# Why can't I find my express code at AWS EB'S EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had to change minor code of webservice which is live at AWS EB in Seoul region.
I tried to access EC2 instance of the EB environment using ssh but I can't not find any code!

my terminal screen shot after I connect to the instance:
[image: my terminal screen shot after I connect to the instance]

I'm curious where are the codes and while I connect to the instance, the service was well running.

p.s. it's a Express project with MongoDB connected

Comment: Why are you editing any code via SSH when the changes made directly to EBS instances could be lost permanently as a result of auto-scaling? Why bypass a proper deployment??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currently running application code will be stored in:

```
/var/app/current
```

But its better to actually fix your code at the source and redeploy your application bundle if possible.